# Error: Failure parsing JSON in fullcalendar in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, fullcalendar

I have the Error: Failure parsing JSON with this code:

In blade file javascript calendar function:

```
events: "/fullcalender",
```

In Controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
  
        if($request->ajax()) {
       
             $data = Event::whereDate('start', '>=', $request->start)
                       ->whereDate('end',   '<=', $request->end)
                       ->get(['id', 'title', 'start', 'end']);
  
             return response()->json($data);
        }
  
        return view('fullcalender');
    }
```

What is wrong? and what code do you suggest to insert events in calendar ?

Comment: This error is present in the last versions of fullcalendar. The old versions work with this code. Nobody has an idea about a working code ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Split render page and get events in two different functions.

Comment: Man... could you explain in more details? Some code, like you sent in your question would be really appreciated.